# How to show each subreport in a separate Excel sheet

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, export-to-excel

I would like to create a report with *iReport* for *MS Excel*.

My report includes two subreports. I need each subreport in a separate *Excel* sheet, but the generated export file has all data in one sheet.

I don't know which settings for this option required is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this issue with help of [**net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row**](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/config.reference.html#net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row) property.

You can set this **net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row** property for the "sheets break" element in report (for example, *line* or *staticText* element).

In my sample below I've put *line* element to the *Group Footer* band for generating new *sheet* in Excel for a new group.

Here is my sample, master report:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ..>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["path_to_subreport"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT id, addressId FROM document ORDER BY addressId]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="ID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="ADDRESSID" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <group name="addressGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESSID}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupHeader>
            <band height="53">
                <subreport>
                    <reportElement x="189" y="0" width="200" height="31"/>
                    <subreportParameter name="addressId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$F{ADDRESSID}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "subreport_new_sheet_for_excel.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </subreport>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="100" height="20"/>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font isItalic="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[ID]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </band>
        </groupHeader>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="9">
                <line>
                    <reportElement x="1" y="5" width="100" height="1">
                        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row" value="true"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <graphicElement>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    </graphicElement>
                </line>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ID}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

My subreport:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport ...>
    <parameter name="addressId" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT city, street FROM address WHERE id = $P{addressId}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CITY" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="STREET" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="258" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["City: " + $F{CITY}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="258" y="0" width="297" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Street: " + $F{STREET}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The result will be:

[image: The generated report in MS Excel, case of using net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row]

The result ***without*** using of "break" element (I removed the line with ***net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.break.after.row*** property) will be:

[image: The generated report in MS Excel]

---

You can find more about info in [Advanced Excel Features](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html#xlsfeatures) post.

Comment: Thank you.
It works in the preview from IReport, but in my real export are all data in one sheet.

Can i assign names to my excel sheets to customize they?

greetings
Mario

Comment: I use php witch an interface to jasperserver. I send the jrxml file was create in IReport per REST/SOAP on the jasperserver.

Comment: @mario What version of *JR Server* are you using?

Comment: I use jasperserver:4.7.0; Build: 20120815_1737

Comment: @mario I was able to reproduce your issue with *JR Server*. My sample works well with my test Java application (which uses the ***JRXlsExporter***), but not on *JR Server*. I found similar post [Excel report with a sheet per group](http://jasperforge.org/node/531471) on http://jasperforge.org - the result of export was different with *iReport* and *JR Server*. I think it will be better and very helpful to post new question with this issue